# How to use Docker's COPY/ADD instructions to copy a single file to an image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to copy a single file from the root of the build context into a newly created directory in a docker image.

The Dockerfile that I am using is as follows:

```
FROM debian:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY test.txt /usr/src/app
```

The test.txt file is a simple ASCII text file as follows:

```
$ cat test.txt 
This is a test
```

However, when I build this image I get an image stating that the destination path is not a directory.

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.608 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM debian:latest
 ---> 9a61b6b1315e
Step 1 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 86bd44a8776e
Step 2 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ed6771adc681
Step 3 : ADD test.txt /usr/src/app
stat /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/ee5b9b7029f2adf27d332cbb0d98d6ad9927629a7569fd2d9574cb767b23547b/rootfs/usr/src/app/test.txt: not a directory
```

I have tried using multiple combinations of docker versions, base images, and distributions with docker installed. I have also tried using ADD instead of COPY but the result is the same.

I am currently trying this on CentOS 7 with the following docker version installed:

```
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

What I have noticed is that I can copy a directory, but not a file. For example, if I create a "test" directory in the build context root and put test.txt inside the test directory then I can copy the directory successfully:

```
FROM debian:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY test /usr/src/app
```

Note that in the above Dockerfile I copy the entire ./test directory rather than just ./test.txt. This build successfully.

The [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy) has the following sample use case for the COPY instruction which is similar to what I am trying to do:

```
COPY hom?.txt /mydir/
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? How can I go about copying a single file?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[As stated in the Dockerfile documentation:](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add)

> - If `<src>` is any other kind of file [besides a local `tar` archive], it is copied individually along with its metadata. In this case, if `<dest>` ends with a trailing slash `/`, it will be considered a directory and the contents of `<src>` will be written at `<dest>/base(<src>)`.
> - If `<dest>` does not end with a trailing slash, it will be considered a regular file and the contents of `<src>` will be written at `<dest>`.

Thus, you have to write `COPY test.txt /usr/src/app/` with a trailing `/`.

Comment: That smells like rsync. I always have to double check that.

Comment: For me, it worked also without the trailing line (Docker 18.09.5). `COPY` still is something tricky (have a look on all issues on SO and GitHub).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was adding a path based on the `docker-compose.yml` instead of the `Dockerfile`:

File structure

```
.
..
/docker-compose.yml
/docker/
/docker/php/
/docker/php/Dockerfile
/docker/php/my_file
```

and in `/` I was running `docker-compose up --build`.

instead of `COPY docker/php/my_file /some/location` I needed to run `COPY my_file /some/location`