# copy a single file to docker image

Tags: docker

I have a situation where I have to copy a single file into docker image.

when I am using :

```
COPY ./folder_source /folder_destination
```

its copying all its contents from folder_source to folder_destination. Till this point I am okay to handle file movement. But I am not able to find a way to copy a single file to docker image.

```
COPY ./setup_server.sh /folder_destination
```

seems like COPY always expects a folder as a source.
Is there any way out to that problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Docker's COPY/ADD instructions to copy a single file to an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640660/how-to-use-dockers-copy-add-instructions-to-copy-a-single-file-to-an-image)

Answer (score 2):

When you `COPY` into a directory it must end with a `/`. For further information please refer to [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#copy).

Comment: well yes that will work, but I have tried without a / , but it did work. I meant all the contents of the source folder get copied to the destination.

Comment: Then, if the source is a directory, you might want to use [`ADD`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add) instead.

Comment: I need a solution for adding a single file not all contents of a folder.

Comment: `ADD ./setup_server.sh /folder_destination/`