# How to copy a single file using Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, nuget

I am trying to build an ASP.NET Core project using `Dockerfile`. I need to use multiple package-sources to restore the project. so I defined the package-sources into a `NuGet.config` file.

Using docker, I want to copy the `NuGet.config` file to my working directory so that the `dotnet restore` command can use it to restore from.

Here is how my `Dockerfile` look like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
LABEL stage=build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy and build
COPY ./src /app
COPY ./NuGet.config /app
RUN dotnet restore /app/Project.Web --configfile ./app/NuGet.config
RUN dotnet publish /app/Project.Web -c Release -o ./build/release --framework net6.0 --no-restore
```

Unfortunately, the above script errors on this line `COPY ./NuGet.config /app`

> => ERROR [build-env 4/6] COPY ./NuGet.config /app
> failed to compute cache key: "/NuGet.config" not found: not found

How can I correctly copy the `NuGet.config` file over to my working directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Docker's COPY/ADD instructions to copy a single file to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640660/how-to-use-dockers-copy-add-instructions-to-copy-a-single-file-to-an-image)

Comment: TL;DR; add a `/` after the app => `COPY  ./NuGet.config /app/`

Comment: @Kenny thank you for the comment. this did not fix the problem. I get `failed to compute cache key: "/NuGet.config" not found: not found` the NuGet.config file is located at the same directory as the Dockerfile

Comment: After a quick search, it might be because of the .dockerignore or the .gitignore. If the config is listed inside one of them it won't copy

Comment: That indeed was the issue! I had to add `!NuGet.config` into `.dockerignore` file and the copy worked